# How to use Excel autofill on a sheet reference?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

My current formula is `=INDIRECT("'"&$U$4&"'!B5")` where `U4` is the name of a worksheet I am referencing from and `B5` is the source cell in the referenced sheet. When I drag this formula horizontally or vertically, `!B5` does not autofill. It remains `!B5` in all cells. I want it to autofill to `C5`,`D5`,etc. horizontally and `B6`,`B7`,etc. when dragged vertically.
I have tried using `=INDIRECT("'"&$U$4&COLUMN(B1)&"'!$b$1")` but it returns #REF.

Comment: It looks like you understand you have to change your hardcoded`!B5` to become a formula. To get you moving again use the `ADDRESS()` function in place of `B5` portion of your hardcoded cell address

Comment: =INDIRECT("'"&$U$4&"'!"&ADDRESS(ROW(B5);COLUMN(B5)))